# Getting data in one view from other actions or simple queries in cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

**cakePHP 2.3**

In my index action of my Items controller i am having a straight forward loop to display Items:

```
<?php foreach ($items as $item): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php
                echo $item['Item']['id'];
                if($this->Session->check('validated')){
                    echo $this->Html->image('/img/action_delete.png',array(
                        'url'=>array('controller' => 'items','action'=>'markdelete',$item['Item']['id'])
                    ));
                    echo $this->Html->image('/img/action_edit.png',array(
                        'url'=>array('controller' => 'items','action'=>'edit',$item['Item']['id'])
                    ));
                }
                ?>
            </td>
            <td><?php 
                echo $this->Html->link($item['Item']['item_category'], array('controller' => 'items','action'=>'index',$item['Item']['item_category'])); 
                ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php 
                    echo $this->Html->link($item['Item']['item_title'], array('controller' => 'items', 'action' => 'view', $item['Item']['id']));
                ?>
            </td>
            <td><?php 
            if($item['Item']['item_photo_url'] != '')    {
                echo $this->Html->link('Link','/img/'.$item['Item']['item_photo_url'],array('target'=>'_blank'));    
            } else {
                echo '---';
            }
                ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $item['Item']['item_description']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $item['Item']['item_price']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

However, i need to create on the top of the page a section where i will have a link menu of the item_category field from my Items table.

item_category field is a simple varchar field in my Items table. I just like to make a distinct out of them and output as links.

How should i do it? Should i try and create a helper and include it in the view? If so how the helper should look like?

I understand that i would break MVC logic by using models in helpers but how else?

**ADDED:**

I just tried to do it through elements and it works, but is that the appropriate way?

Element source:

```
<?php
    $cat = $this->requestAction('/items/categories');
    echo __('Κατηγορίες:  ');
    foreach ($cat as $category) {
        echo $this->Html->link($category['Item']['item_category'], array('controller' => 'items','action'=>'index',$category['Item']['item_category'])). '  |  '; 
    }
    echo $this->Html->link('Ολες', array('controller' => 'items','action'=>'index')); 
?>
```

Controller action:

```
public function Categories() {
        $categories = $this->Item->find('all',array(
            'fields' => array('DISTINCT item_category'),
            'order' => array('item_category')
        ));
        return $categories;
    }
```

**Summary of Request:**

Lets say i have a table items that has a field item_category. this field is varchar and is not a primary key of another table.

Also i have an index action in the Items controller where i just list ALL the items from the table.

What i need is to make a select distinct on item_category field and put it on the header of the page.

Comment: Even after editing it is not clear what you want to do.

From the idea I get after reading your post twice is that you already have the data in the Items model, so you just need to loop twice to get them in two different places?

If your problem is in getting the data with distinct, then just run the find with distinct in your controller and pass it as a different variable. But in that case, perhaps you need to rethink your DB structure and normalize the category fields in another table.

Comment: @user221931: sorry for not being so clear. First i dont want to normalize the categories since this is a very simple app. My main question is what is the best practice to bring into the view data from  2 controller actions. As you can see in my post i am using a second action Categories and i am making the distinct in there. This action feeds an element and this is how i got it working.I just don't know if this way is not the preferred ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, the preferred way would be to normalize the table :)

Not only it is faster for the DB to run a `SELECT *` on the (proposed) `categories` table rather than a `DISTINCT` over a number of VARCHAR data on all the items, it is also best practise when working with RDBMS and CakePHP, plus cake will make it transparent for you to work on the data so it's not really more complicated.

So although I can't see how "being a simple app" justifies your choice - one that in the long run might give you more trouble than it might look now - the way you're doing it will work fine. Just note that `requestAction` should be avoided without caching for performance.

If you only need this information inside the `ItemsController` you're probably better adding the find to your `ItemModel` as a `public function categories()` that returns the data from the find and then in the controller do something like

```
$itemCategories = $this->Item->categories();
$this->set('itemCategories', $itemCategories);
```

You can still use the element, just pass it `$itemCategories`

Comment: So this is the way to include more than one action in my view? And if i dont want to use requestaction what should i do in my element?

Comment: CakePHP is an MVC framework. In MVC paradigm models should contain most of the business logic (say 60-80% of the code), controllers do the middleman/glue/preparation of data and views should be very thin - just to display those data. So your question of 'multiple actions per view' is probably due to not recognizing MVC flow. `requestAction` can be thought of as a "hack" where when you've already been through router->controller->model->controller->view and you go back to another controller->model->controller to get data. It is justified in some cases but not as a general rule.

Comment: And just to clarify, if you need the item categories to display in all or most of your pages then `requestAction` is the preferred solution, it matches exactly the pattern it was meant for. Used with caching it will be as good as having static code.

If you need the categories only in a few actions in the items controller or a couple more then push the logic in the model and have the controller ask for it in each action that is needed. 

But the best solution (even if `requestAction` is used) is a new table/model, like I said.

Comment: Yes the requestaction was ment to be like you say , just to appear in every page. thanks!

Comment: Glad I helped! If you're still not convinced of the advantages of normalizing to a new table, think how much (generally inefficient) code you will need for things that come up commonly, like needing to display only the active categories, the last created category, change the name of a category for all items that carry it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your ItemsController:

```
public function index() {
    $categories = $this->Item->Category->find('all');
    $items = $this->Item->paginate();
    $this->set(compact('items','categories'));
}
```

Use the $catigories variable in your view as you wish

Comment: Probably i wasnt clear enough. i will update my post in order to be clearer